# Puppeteer prevent "pause on debugging" aka disable all breakpoints

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I need scraping with headless mode a site with a lot of `debugger;`

There is a way to prevent pause on debugger?

I try to send on load CTRL+F8 and F8 with this code but without success!

```
await crt_page.keyboard.down('Control');
await crt_page.keyboard.press('F8');
await crt_page.keyboard.up('Control');
await crt_page.keyboard.press('F8');
```

any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Puppeteer is automatically pressing keys inside the `page`, and not the browser.

So i think the solution is to install a npm package `robotjs` to do things outside the browser.

Hope this helps you!

Don't forget to select my answer as the correct answer if this code worked.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const robot = require('robotjs')

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    const open = await page.goto('https://www.example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })

    await page.waitFor(4000)
    await robot.keyToggle(']','down','control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'

    await page.waitFor(500)
    await robot.keyToggle(']','down','control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'

    await page.waitFor(500)
    await robot.keyToggle(']', 'up', 'control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'

    await page.waitFor(1000)
    await robot.keyToggle('f8','down','control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'

    await page.waitFor(500)
    await robot.keyToggle('f8', 'up', 'control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'


})()
```

To debugging your robotjs, is it worked or not, try this code.

Code below run puppeteer and change the URL using `robotjs`.

If this also not worked on your server, then i'm sorry i can't help you.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const robot = require('robotjs')
const pageURL = 'https://www.google.com'
const normal_Strings = ['`','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','-','=','[',']','\\',';','\'',',','.','/']
const shiftedStrings = ['~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','{','}','|',':','"','<','>','?']

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    const open = await page.goto('https://www.example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })

    console.log('First URL:')
    console.log(await page.url())
    await robot.keyToggle('l','down','control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'
    await page.waitFor(500)
    await robot.keyToggle('l', 'up', 'control') // For Mac, change 'control' to 'command'
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    for (let num in pageURL) {
        if (shiftedStrings.includes(pageURL[num])) {
            var key = normal_Strings[ shiftedStrings.indexOf(pageURL[num]) ]

            await robot.keyToggle( key,'down','shift')
            await page.waitFor(300)
            await robot.keyToggle( key, 'up', 'shift')
            await page.waitFor(300)
        }
        await robot.keyTap(pageURL[num])
        await page.waitFor(200)
    }
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    await robot.keyTap('enter')

    await page.waitForSelector('img#hplogo[alt="Google"]', {timeout: 0})
    console.log('Second URL:')
    console.log(await page.url())
})()
```

Comment: Sure, my pleasure. Don't forget select my answer as correct answer if you found this code running well.

Comment: sorry but don't work... I has trying in headless and normal...

Comment: what errors displayed in console (if there is any) ?
 
It runs well in my Mac. Do you have change the `'command'` to `'control'` ?
 
Have you installed `robotjs` package by type: `npm i robotjs` ?

Comment: No error in console, simply don't press CTRL + F8 for disable all breakpoint. 
I have replace command with control and I have try to change the button order... 
I think the problem is that dev tools is "client side" not server one, so, you can't disable breakpoints form  bot

Comment: If you're running puppeteer in `headless: true` mode then this script won't help you.

I've made a script to debug if it's works or not; This script only change the URL by typing URL in Chromium address bar.

Comment: As you see from my question I ask for headless :)

Comment: So i'm sorry then i can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had some struggles scraping a page that had a `debug` statement within some js.

I just changed dev tools to false.  The dev tool pane isn't there and the debug statement doesn't cause issues.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  devtools: false,
  slowMo: 100
});
```